# How can one QtQuickItem find another based on id

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qt5, qtquick2

I have two classes `A` and `B` that both inherit `QtQuickItem` in **Qt5**.

How can I tell one of them about the other based on their *id* when I instantiate them from **QML** like so:

```
A{
  id:lol
}

B{
  id:bob
  myCustomPropertyThatAcceptsID:lol
}
```

In other words, how would the property `myCustomPropertyThatAcceptsID` look like in **C++**, and how would I get a pointer to the instance of `A` with the id "lol" from **C++**?

**EDIT: After some confusion in the comments, I have decided to update this question with an example:**

The `VideoOut` QML Type in Qt5 has a [source](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtmultimedia-videooutput.html#source-prop) property. This is set to the id of either a `Camera` or `MediaPlayer` instance in QML to tell it from where it should get the video stream to show. I want to do the same but using my own two classes in C++ inheriting from `QtQuickItem`. How whould I implement my properties in C++ to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: `id` is a pointer in terms of C++ but for QML only. it is assigned to an object at parsing time and so not changeable. Since it is not based on Q_PROPERTY it's not accesible from C++. To access an object you can use `objectName` and so `root->findChild<QObject*>()` from C++

Comment: youtCustomPropertyThatAcceptsID will not be expecting an ID but a `QObject`, the id is just the means to reference it. Also, for god sake, use that spacebar

Comment: @folibis so my property will actually receive a pointer to QObject automatically when I do it like this?

Comment: @ddriver notfolliwingwhyshouldIusethatspacebat?

Comment: I don't really understand what are you trying to do. You get pointer to `A` in C++ and you want to get pointer to `B`? If yes so `findChild` it what you need. Just add `objectName:"someName"` to `B` and do `A->parentItem->findChild<QQuickItem *>("someName")`

Comment: @folibis: An example is in order. The VideoOutput QML type has a source property (http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtmultimedia-videooutput.html#source-prop). You can set this to the id of a MediaPlayer instance or Camera. This tells that particular VideoOutput instance about another MediaPlayer instance both instanciated in QML. How must my property look like in C++ for me to be able to do the same?

Comment: I guess it have to be something like `Q_PROPERTY(QQuickItem * b READ b WRITE setB NOTIFY bChanged)` with suitable `b()`, `setB()` and `bChanged()` in `A` class. So you will be able to assign `B` to `A` in `QML` - `b: bob`

Comment: @folibis Put it in an answer and I will accept it!